# Estimating progress of embedded python script in C++

Tags: python, c++, progress-bar, boost-python

**The introduction**

Let's say I have a C++ app, with embedded python script. The Script does some heavy calculation, which take significant time to be ended. I can extract the result of the script, when it is finished. However it would be convenient, to know what is the actual stay of calculation - is it 10% or maybe half of job is done at the moment? Here's an example code (using `boot python`):

`app.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

int main()
    try
    {
    Py_Initialize();
    object module = import("__main__");
    object name_space = module.attr("__dict__");
    exec_file("Script.py", name_space, name_space);

    object MyFunc = name_space["MyFunc"];
    object result = MyFunc();

    double sum = extract<double>(sum);}

Py_Finalize();
```

`Script.py`

```
def MyFunc():
    cont = 0
    while (cont < 10000):
        #...some calculations here, increasing "result" value on each step...
        cont +=1
    return result
```

**The problem**

If the code would be all in C++ I could use native framework tools like `emit`, to access GUI progress bar slot, and update its value. But what in the case described above? In console app I could print `cont` every time, directly from python. However it is not solution for any C++ with GUI. Is there any way to determinate, from C++ code level, on which lap of loop is the execution of `Script.py`? Or maybe there is any other solution to serve the progress bar?

Comment: Give the Python function some callback it can use to report progress back to the C++ part.

Comment: Good idea. Passing simple `void callback(double prog)` with `MyFunc(callback)` and call `callback(cont)` inside while loop do what I need.

Comment: Do you want to self-answer this one, since you already figured it out, or should I write up an answer myself? Some easy reputation points for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To sum up the conclusions from comment section:**
The problem can be solved by giving a callback to function called from python. The .cpp would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

int main(){
    Py_Initialize();
    object module = import("__main__");
    object name_space = module.attr("__dict__");
    exec_file("Script.py", name_space, name_space);

    object MyFunc = name_space["MyFunc"];
    object result = MyFunc();

    double sum = extract<double>(sum);}

    Py_Finalize();}

callback(int cont){
    int cont_final = 10000;
    double progr = cont / cont_final * 100;
    cout << cont << "\n";}
```

Keep in mind that the callback need to be static member or free function (in this case I've shown the second option). If you need to pass also state (for example due of GUI), look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010451/how-to-send-signal-using-callback-called-from-external-script).

Python part would be:

```
def MyFunc(callback):
    cont = 0
    while (cont < 10000):
        #...some calculations here, increasing "result" value on each step...
        cont +=1
        callback(cont) #Here we call progress update
    return result
```

And that's it - in the results the progress indicator from 0 to 100 will be printed to console.

Answer (score 1):

You could send a signal from the python program back to the C++ program, something like:

```
if cont % 100 == 0:
    os.kill(cpp_progs_pid, signal.SIGUSR1)
```

then use a signal handler for that signal in C++ to use `emit`.

EDIT: In your C++ code you'll need to pass the program's pid, something like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
...
int pid = getpid(); // python's cpp_progs_pid
exec_file("Script.py", name_space, name_space, pid);
```

And something like this to handle the signal:

```
#include <signal.h>
...
void my_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGUSR1)
    {
        // code to use emit
    }
}
...
signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler);  // set your signal handler
```

The signal handler `my_handler` will be called asynchronously while your C++ program is running so you must be cautious about any side effects. It must be set, once, before you call your python script.

Comment: Can you provide more details? I'm not familiar with `os` module. If i understand it correctly this would send the same signal at every 1% of progress. But what is the declaration of `cpp_progs_pid`? And how to handle this signal on the C++ site of code?