# How to send signal using callback called from external script?

Tags: python, c++, qt, signals, boost-python

**Introduction**

I'm trying to update QT GUI element basing on the state of calculations in embedded python script. I'm able to extract required values from python, but can't set a reference to c++ object to make it work.

**The details**

Let's assume python code is called (in calc.cpp) this way:

```
void class_name::transfer(varA, varB, varC)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    emit inprogress(70); //HERE IT WORKS
    object module = import("__main__");
    object name_space = module.attr("__dict__");
    exec_file("MyModule.py", name_space, name_space);

    object MyFunc = name_space["MyFunc"];
    object result = MyFunc(varA, varB, varC, callback);

    double ret = extract<double>(result);
    Py_Finalize();
}

void class_name::callback(double t_prog, double t_final)
{
    progr = (double)t_prog / t_final * 100;
    cout << progr; //To check if value is updating (It is)
    emit inprogress(progr); //HERE IT FAIL
}
```

`callback` is a `static` member function (in calc.cpp) I use to extract some values, indicating on which stage is calculation inside python script. It is called in loop from python script (MyModule.py):

```
while r.successful() and k < num_steps:
    r.integrate(r.t + delta_t)
    callback(r.t, t_final)
```

However the compilation fails with following error:

> illegal call to nonstatic member function
>
> nonstatic member reference must be relative to specific object

It is related to `emit inprogress(progr);`

**The Question**

I think I should pass a reference to the object **from my c++ to python, and back to c++ with callback**. But I can't find a way how to do this. What's the correct way to do this?

**Tested ideas (still not working)**

1. I was trying to pass it simple like:
   `void class_name::callback(double t_prog, double t_final, class_name &cssd)` but python seems to can't convert it automatically.
2. Creating of new class object:

   ```
   class_name cs;
   emit cs.inprogress(progr);
   ```

   Compile without error, but signal never reach the slot - it creates new object instead of refer to existing.

Comment: where is the code to connect the signal to slot?

Comment: I included it in Edit.

Comment: I reworked the question to actual state of my knowledge.

Comment: Make the callback an object that will hold a reference to the instance of `class_name`. Give it a method like `dispatch(double t_prog, double t_final)` which will do `instance.callback(t_prog, t_final)` (where the existing `callback` becomes a non-static member -- might want to rename it). | Or you could just feed a pointer as an extra argument of the existing static callback function, but that's not so nice.

Comment: @Dan Mašek - It sound interesting however you described it so shorthand I'm not sure how to do this. Can you add your though as an answer? I will "accept" it if it will works so future users may use it.

Comment: There you go. Regarding your ideas - #1 would need class `class_name` exposed to Python (at least the class itself, not any member functions). #2 won't work, since you create a new instance (but what you need is the original one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to add some additional state to the callback, namely a reference to the instance of the class whose member function we want to invoke.

To do this, we can use a class. To make the functionality equivalent to just using a simple static callback function, let's define `operator()` (i.e. make it a functor), and also expose this operator to Python.

Let's suppose we have the following application class:

```
class app
{
public:
    explicit app(std::string name) : name_(std::move(name)) {}

    int run();

    void callback(double t_prog, double t_final);

private:
    std::string name_;
};
```

In `run()` we execute our Python script, and we want it to call the member function `callback` of the current instance.

Let's define the following callback handler class:

```
class callback_handler
{
public:
    explicit callback_handler(app& a) : app_(a) {}

    void operator()(double t_prog, double t_final)
    {
        app_.callback(t_prog, t_final);
    }

private:
    app& app_;
};
```

We need to expose this class to Python, but don't want to be able to create new instances from Python,  nor do we really want it to be copied (although it doesn't really matter here, since our state only consists of references).

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cbtest)
{
    bp::class_<callback_handler, boost::noncopyable>("callback_handler", bp::no_init)
        .def("__call__", &callback_handler::operator())
        ;
};
```

At the start of our application, we need to make sure to initialize our module before we use it -- call `initcbtest();` right after initializing the Python interpreter.

Now we can use our callback handler in the following manner (The Python code stays the same, since the object is callable):

```
    callback_handler cbh(*this);
    bp::object result = MyFunc(1, 10, 2, boost::ref(cbh));
    std::cout << "result = " << bp::extract<double>(result) << "\n";
```

---

#### Sample Code

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

#include <iostream>
// ============================================================================
namespace bp = boost::python;
// ============================================================================
class app
{
public:
    explicit app(std::string name) : name_(std::move(name)) {}

    int run();

    void callback(double t_prog, double t_final);

private:
    std::string name_;
};
// ============================================================================
class callback_handler
{
public:
    explicit callback_handler(app& a) : app_(a) {}

    void operator()(double t_prog, double t_final)
    {
        app_.callback(t_prog, t_final);
    }

private:
    app& app_;
};
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cbtest)
{
    bp::class_<callback_handler, boost::noncopyable>("callback_handler", bp::no_init)
        .def("__call__", &callback_handler::operator())
        ;
};
// ============================================================================
void app::callback(double t_prog, double t_final)
{
    std::cout << "CB(" << name_ << ") " << t_prog << " " << t_final << "\n";
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int app::run()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    initcbtest();

    try {
        bp::object module = bp::import("__main__");
        bp::object name_space = module.attr("__dict__");
        bp::exec_file("MyModule.py", name_space, name_space);

        bp::object MyFunc = name_space["MyFunc"];

        callback_handler cbh(*this);
        bp::object result = MyFunc(1, 10, 2, boost::ref(cbh));
        std::cout << "result = " << bp::extract<double>(result) << "\n";
    } catch (bp::error_already_set&) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
// ============================================================================
int main()
{
    app a("TestApp");

    return a.run();
}
// ============================================================================
```

---

#### Python Script

File `MyModule.py`:

```
def MyFunc(a, b, c, callback):
    result = 0
    for i in range(a, b, c):
        result += i
        callback(i, b)
    return result
```

---

#### Console Output

```
CB(TestApp) 0 10
CB(TestApp) 2 10
CB(TestApp) 4 10
CB(TestApp) 6 10
CB(TestApp) 8 10
result = 20
```

Comment: That solved the problem. I was also trying luck with functor, but I never use it before so I did some basic mistakes. The above presented implementation works well - I only had to insert `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cbtest)` in .cpp not .h, because of some strange problems with multiple declarations. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Karls Yeah, `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` can't be in the header -- if you look at [the implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/python/blob/ac62db1cf17c0af44dc2b2117f9ddeee327e5e7c/include/boost/python/module_init.hpp#L59), it generates the module initialization functions (in this case `initcbtest` and `init_module_cbtest`) and you provide the body of the second function. Since the functions aren't `inline`, having it in a header can cause them to be defined multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the problem is that you are calling `emit c_n.inprogress(progr);`, where the argument of the signal `progr` is of type `double`, whereas  in the `connect(sender, SIGNAL( inprogress(int) ), ui->progressBar, SLOT( setValue(int) ) );` the signal takes an integer as argument. In older Qt versions(older than Qt5), signals and slots must use exactly the same types, meaning that the implicit conversion may not occur.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/23302/connect-diferent-signals-and-slost-each-other/4

Comment: I also thought it may be the problem, so I even tried to do `emit c_n.inprogress(50)`, with hardcoded integer. Nothing changed. As you can see above I use static function, so probably I need a reference to the object, but I don't know how to pass it, as callback is called not from c++ but from python.

Comment: So the error is called on the line  `emit inprogress(progr);` ? Because the problem might be the fact that the function setValue(int) which is called is trying to set the value of a class member, but it has no right to do so because it is not defined as a member of the same class. It's difficult to say without the rest of the code

Comment: yes, the error is called exactly on this lane. I can call it from non-static function, for example from `transfer`. For example: `Py_Initialize(); emit inprogress(70);` - this will works. But when I call a callback (so static function) it return me the described above error.

Comment: The fact is that static member functions can only access static data members of the same class. So in the case of function transfer() it works, as this function is non static. This is something intern to C++ language and has nothing to do with Python or reference. The way around it could be defining the member you are trying to access as static one. However, signals by default cannot be static, so I think the best thing to do is create another non-static function, which calls `emit inprogress`, then call that function from `class_name::callback`

Comment: It ends with the same - `illegal call to nonstatic member function`. I created function `class_name::emit_callback(double progr)`, and called it from `class_name::callback` this way: `emit_callback(progr);` so it still miss the object, nothing changed.

Comment: Does the function class_name::callback have to be static? Because in Qt, there's no actual need for static functions, when you can simply use signal-slot mechanism.

Comment: And how you want to use non-static function as a callback? As far as I know it is not technically possible. It's not due QT, it's because I need to pass it to other scope.

Comment: Ok, this works for me: inside the function `callback` you should define a dummy object of class_name, for instance `class_name test`, then call `test.emit_callback`. Having an object, you can call the function.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Yes, I know this trick, but it seems it creates new object instead of referring to existing one. The signal goes to nowhere, never reach the slot. Before "edit" I provided this, you can even see a residue in your answer (`emit c_n.inprogress(progr);`). So it is not a real solution - it only prevent the error but the signal never reach its target. You can test it on your own - create simple slot in one file, call a method from second file, and try to emit signal from static function in the second file - it will gives no error, but also no effect.

Comment: The problem is quite clear from the error message -- the OP is trying to (indirectly) invoke a non-static member function from a static member function. | Creating a new instance of the class is rather pointless, when you want to invoke the member function on the original instance. If it doesn't matter, the member function should have been static in the first place.